# JavaScript Eval to replace empty spaces with <SP>, literal

Tags: vba, eval, imacros

I am using iMacros & VBA.  I created a string in VBA that replaces empty spaces with <SP> so I can pass it to an iMacros script.  The problem is iMacros takes the <SP> as a space and not as a string.  I tried to tweak VBA but when its passed to iMacros as a variableits just empty spaces.

i figured I try to do an eval in iMacros directly but am stuck with the proper syntax.

```
Set Name "Chris Tony James"
Set newName EVAL("\"{{Name}}\".replace(/ //g, \"&lt;SP&gt;\";")
```

i have tried a million varieties, even using split.join.  I just cant get it. 
thanks for any help

**Before**: Chris Tony James

**After**:  Chris<SP>Tony<SP>James

Answer (score 0):

It must be something like that:

```
Set newName EVAL("\"{{Name}}\".replace(/\s+/g, \"&lt;SP&gt;\";")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Set Name Chris<SP>Tony<SP>James
```

Is all that is required to use `<SP>` in place of spaces in a variable in iMacros. Omit the `"` marks.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.